# Meteor / React - Material UI component Chip not recognizing onRequestDelete function

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI's chip element in my application and according to the documentation

`onRequestDelete` - `Callback function fired when the delete icon is clicked. If set, the delete icon will be shown.`

```
import React from 'react'
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data'
import Chip from 'material-ui/Chip'

class InfluencerChips extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentInfluencers: [{name: {first: 'Test', last: 'User'}, relationship: 'Friend'}]
    }

    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this)
  }

  handleDelete(id){
    console.log(id)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        { this.state.currentInfluencers.map((influencer, k) =>
          <Chip
            key={k}
            onRequestDelete={this.handleDelete(influencer.id)}
          >
            {influencer.name.first}
          </Chip>
        )}

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I can't seem to get the 'handleDelete' function to be recognized as a function. It renders this:

[image]

But when I change the line to this:

```
onRequestDelete={function(){}}
```

it Renders properly with the close icon like this

[image]

So is handleDelete(id) actually a function? What is the React way to handle this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

`this.handleDelete(influencer.id)` is not a function, its an return value, returned by the function
`this.handleDelete` is a function, but you need the value, instead of the event

change it, to this:

`onRequestDelete={() => this.handleDelete(influencer.id)}`

Comment: Ah that makes sense, that worked. That is even in the documentation, I deleted it and forgot. Thank you very much

Comment: @ruevaughn np, this are the small bits, that are missed / forgotten very often ;) please accept, if it is answering your question

Comment: Yeah had to wait a bit before it would let me accept, yeah bunch of these small things i'm noticing!